# Passing a list variable to a class function

Tags: python

```
import csv
class Team:
    def __init__(self, roster):
        self.roster = roster

def GetRoster(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.roster)

with open('CavsRoster.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

for p in data:
    player = p[1]

guy = Team(player)  
print(guy.GetRoster())
```

Whenever I pass this variable into my GetRoster function, I only receive the last list of my csv file. I'm still very new and not even sure I'm tackling this issue in the right way.

What I'm trying to accomplish is, getting the first piece of data in this CSV file, in this case the name of the player of the entire roster, then passing that list into my classes function as the attribute.

I've tried to watch a video from Corey Schafer on youtube and it only left me very confused. I dont know what I dont know

This is part of my CSV file:

```
,Max Strus,G,6-5,215,March 28 1996,us,4,Lewis (IL) DePaul
,Georges Niang,F,6-7,230,June 17 1993,us,7,Iowa State
,Caris LeVert,G-F,6-6,205,August 25 1994,us,7,Michigan
,Ty Jerome,G,6-5,195,July 8 1997,us,4,Virginia
,Emoni Bates  (TW),G,6-10,170,January 28 2004,us,R,Memphis Eastern Michigan
```

Comment: Please fix the code's indentation.

Comment: It would also be worth you adding a few lines of the CSV to your post so that readers can understand what the rows and columns actually represent and help you.

Comment: What is `for p in data:` meant to be achieving?

Comment: Peter, I thought I needed to loop over the list I created to get each name.

Comment: @ots but what do you think `player = p[1]` does?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're trying to collect the players' names for the roster, you can do that as follows:

```
import csv

class Team:
    def __init__(self, roster):
        self.roster = roster

    def GetRoster(self):
        return "{}".format(self.roster)

with open("CavsRoster.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    names = [p[1] for p in reader]

team = Team(names)
print(team.GetRoster())
# ['Max Strus', 'Georges Niang', 'Caris LeVert', 'Ty Jerome', 'Emoni Bates  (TW)']
```

Additionally, some of your variable names are misleading so it's worth paying attention to that.

Comment: Why make a list first? Just do `names = [p[1] for p in reader]`

Comment: @Barmar I was limiting the delta between the OP's code and my answer, to simplify, but agree that's better and have made that change, thanks.

Comment: yeah, noticed that after I commented, sorry